# How to upload a captured and displayed video via phonegap android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, video

I am using the code below to capture video and display it on the app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Video</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
}

// A button will call this function
//
function captureVideo() {
    // Launch device video recording application,
    // allowing user to capture only 1 video clips with 10mins duration
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1, duration: 10});
}
// Called when capture operation is finished
// to display the captured video
function captureSuccess(s) {
console.log("Success");
console.dir(s[0]);
var v = "<video controls='controls'>";
v += "<source src='" + s[0].fullPath + "' type='video/mp4'>";
v += "</video>";
document.querySelector("#videoArea").innerHTML = v;
}
// This function is to upload the captured video when the user
// clicks upload video button
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {

var ft = new FileTransfer(),
    path = mediaFile.fullPath,
    name = mediaFile.name;
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.mimeType = "documents";
options.fileName = name;
options.chunkedMode = true;

ft.upload(path,
    "http://www.example.com/upload.php",
    function(result) {
        alert('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
        alert(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
    },
    function(error) {
        alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
    },
    options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="captureVideo();">Capture Video</button> <br><br>
    <div id="videoArea"></div><br><br>
    <button id="uploadvid" onclick="uploadFile();">Upload Video</button>

</body>
</html>
```

After displaying the captured video, when the "Upload Video" button is clicked nothing happens. The video is not uploaded to the server. Meanwhile, if I replaced the captureSuccess(s) function with the following code;

```
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }
}
```

the captured video is uploaded to the server successfully though without preview.

Please could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong. I want the user to have a look at the captured video first before clicking the "Upload Video" button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `onclick="uploadFile();"`is not accepting any argument but your function `uploadFile(mediaFile)` is expecting an argument.

```
<button id="uploadvid" onclick="uploadFile();">Upload Video</button>
```

My suggestion for solution is ,create the button element as

```
<button id="uploadvid" >Upload Video</button>
```

Write your function captureSuccess as

```
function captureSuccess(s) {
  console.log("Success");
  console.dir(s[0]);
  var v = "<video controls='controls'>";
  v += "<source src='" + s[0].fullPath + "' type='video/mp4'>";
  v += "</video>";
  document.querySelector("#videoArea").innerHTML = v;

  //here you write logic when upload button is clicked
  $("#uploadvid").on("click",function(){
     uploadFile(s[0]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiran for your reply. I was away for almost a day since I posted this question and have just returned. I will test the suggestion you gave and reply back. Thanks again.

Comment: I observed that the code you added is inside the captureSuccess(s) function. Thus I can't have access to the code you added by just clicking on "Upload Video" button because it does not call the "captureSuccess(s) function. And if I have to bring out that code outside the "captureSuccess(s) function I wonder if the s[0] will still be available for the .onclick function to capture.

Comment: @Aika The click event gets binded inside the capture success function.So when you click the upload video button it has to work.please try the code.If it doesn't work inform me.I will help you out

Comment: Pls. @Kiran, I am following your advice. Let me try it and give you feedback right away. Thanks for the promise to help me out.

Comment: Hi @Kiran, your suggestion worked well. Thanks a lot. However, I do not know if you could suggest for me how best I could upload the video with form data.

Comment: @Aika create a params object like var params=new object(); Then we can add data's to this params like params.name=$("#name").val (); Add this params to your options like options.params=params;we can get this data from server side like $_POST["name"] if you are using php.